# Como eliminar la carpeta de node_module de mi proyecto react

Tags: reactjs, gitlab

En mi caso ya lamentablemente la he subido, entonces como la elimino, y como hacer para cuando haga un push no la suba nuevamente porque si ya bien me dicen como eliminarla el segundo paso es como no volverle a subir[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para solucionar esto hay que hacer dos simples cosas:

En el archivo `.gitignore` del proyecto añadir `/node_modules`.

Después ejecutar en la terminal dentro del proyecto:

```
git rm --cached -r ./node_modules
```

Este comando borra si ha detectado cambios en esa carpeta, y al estar añadido en `.gitignore` no lo vuelve a subir al realizar un `push`, incluso **eliminandolo** del repositorio.

PD: Te aconsejo que añadas también en `.gitignore` la ruta `/src/environments`. Ahí contendrá información delicada sobre cuentas de base de datos y demás que añadas a tu proyecto.

Answer (score 0):

Para ignorar ficheros en tu repo tienes el fichero `.gitignore` en el cual puedes especificar las rutas de los fichero/carpetas que quieras ignorar.

1. Borra la carpeta `node_modules` de tu local
2. Crea el fichero `.gitignore`(con el punto incluido) en la raíz de tu proyecto
3. Añade `node_modules/` o los archivos que no quieras subir a tu repositorio en el fichero `.gitignore`
4. Haz `commit` y sube los cambios a tu repo haciendo un `push`
5. Instala otra vez los paquetes de `node_modules` con `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

Para no volver a subirlo tenes que crear el archivo .gitignore en tu carpeta de git y agregar la carpeta node_modules/ dentro del archivo asi no lo sube cuando hagas el push.

Despues volves a armar el commit y ya va a quedar eliminado de la rama remota en git.

Por lo general cuando creas un nuevo proyecto en React el gitignore se crea automaticamente para no subir ese archivo, ya que de todas maneras se puede crear automaticamente en cualquier ambiente en caso de implementarse.